Placing object in AR without hittest or plane in ios swift
i want to place a object in 3d world space  without the use of hittest or plane detection in ios swift code. Suggest the best method.
Now,  I take the camera center matrix and use simd_mul to place the object, it works but the object gets placed at the centre of the mobile screen. I want to select the x and y positino on the screen 2d coordinate and place the object.
I tried using the unprojectpoint function, to get the AR scene world coordinate of the point i touch on the mobile screen. I get the x, y,z values, they are very close to the values from camera center matrix. When i try to replace the unprojectpoint values in the cameracenter matrix, i dont see a difference in the location of the placed object.
The below code always place object from center screen with specified depth, But i need to place object in user specified position(x,y) of the screen with depth.
2D pixel coordinate system of the renderer to the 3D world coordinate system of the scene.
/* Create a transform with a translation of 0.2 meters in front of the camera. */
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
translation.columns.3.z = -0.2
let transform = simd_mul(view.session.currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)

Refer from :  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arskview/providing_2d_virtual_content_with_spritekit
The code i used for replacing the camera center matrix with the unprojectpoint is
let vpWithZ = SCNVector3(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, z: -1.0)
let worldPoint = sceneView.unprojectPoint(vpWithZ)

var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
        
translation.columns.3.z = Float(Depth)
        
var translation2 = sceneView.session.currentFrame!.camera.transform
translation2.columns.3.x = worldPoint.x
translation2.columns.3.y = worldPoint.y
translation2.columns.3.z = worldPoint.z

let new_transform = simd_mul(translation2, translation)

/* add object name you wanted  in your project*/
let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.03)
let objectNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
 
objectNode.position = SCNVector3(x: transform.columns.3.x, y: transform.columns.3.y, z: transform.columns.3.z)

The below image shows outline of my idea.
Markdown 

Can you please explain why do you want to avoid hittest?

Because, i want to place objects in any place without the need of plane, Also,  I want to dynamically set the depth using a numerical input on the screen. Mostly mid air.

You can still use hittest, get the direction vector and find a point in that direction for the given depth. There are other ways, am sure but this can be easy and efficient
